# Fade/change the color of an SVG Shape over time after being added to a canvas?

Tags: object, svg, shapes

I have created an SVG map that plots tweets live containing particular keywords. I'm drawing each tweet to the screen as a circle (or dot), and after 50 tweets have been added to the map, the oldest one will disappear.

[image]

**I'd like to have some sort of color decay for the circles depending on how long they've been on the map.**

New tweets would pop onto the map and be red. As time passes, points already plotted on the map will slowly fade to black.

Here's where I add the circles to the map:

```
function mapTweet(tweetData) {
    var tipText; // Ignore this. For tweet dot hovering.
    var coordinates = projection([tweetData.geo.coordinates[1], tweetData.geo.coordinates[0]]);

    addCircle(coordinates, tipText);
}

function addCircle(coordinates, tipText, r) {
    tweetNumber++;

    // too many tweets
    if (tweetNumber == 50) {
        tweetNumber = 0;
    }

    //removes expired circles 
    $('#' + tweetNumber).remove();

    var rad;

    //determine if radius size needs to be bumped
    if (arguments.length == 3) {
        rad = r;
    } else {
        rad = 3;
    }

    // add radar-style ping effect
    map.append('svg:circle')
        .style("stroke", "rgba(255,49,49,.7)")
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
        .attr('cx', coordinates[0])
        .attr('cy', coordinates[1])
        .attr('r', 3)
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("r", 60)
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "rgba(255,49,49,0.0001)").transition().duration(2000).remove();

    // add circles representing tweets
    map.append('svg:circle').attr("class", "tweetCircles")
        .attr("id", tweetNumber)
        .style("stroke", "rgba(255,49,49,.7)")
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", "rgba(240,49,49,1)")
        .attr('cx', coordinates[0])
        .attr('cy', coordinates[1])
        .attr('r', rad);

    addTipsy(tipText, tweetNumber); // Ignore this. For tweet dot hovering.
}
```

Once a circle is drawn, does it have to be redrawn to change the color? Or can dots have their attributes changed after being added to the canvas?

How can I decay the color over, say, 20 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Append an [animate](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement) element as a child of the circle

```
.append('svg:animate')
  .attr('attributeName', 'fill')
  .attr('from', 'red')
  .attr('to', 'blue')
  .attr('dur', '20s');
```

This will interpolate from red to blue or whatever colours you choose.

Comment: I'm unsure where to add this. Do I just tack it on to the end where I append the svg:circle?